# laravel - Vuejs routes conflicting with Laravel routes, trying to make an axios request

Tags: laravel, vue.js, routes, axios

I'm trying to make a get request.

My project is set up as a SPA, so VueJS is handling the routes for each of my 'pages'.

I think I've narrowed down that VueJS routes are interfering with the Laravel routing, as whichever invalid endpoint I visit /someEndPoint, under dev tools I always receive the same html response as below. And I can also make a post request and data can be entered into my database which is fine. But whatever get request I attempt it won't enter the specified Controller's function

Here's a standard get request I'm trying to make

```
axios.get('/reservation/date/2018-11-13/')
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log("data", response.data);
    console.log("status", response.status);
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Response with status code 200

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Home Page</title>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="hrfSpnUDNsVv6pLQM4v0UFUk2yrq3m8yPYiss2YT">
    <link href="http://localhost:8000/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <ps-header></ps-header>

      <router-view>

      </router-view>
      <ps-footer></ps-footer>
    </div>
    <script src="http://localhost:8000/js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

VueJS routes - routes.js

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

let routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: require('./components/views/pages/home.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/faq',
    name: 'faq',
    component: require('./components/views/pages/faq.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/register',
    name: 'register',
    component: require('./components/views/pages/register.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login',
    component: require('./components/views/pages/login.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/testPage',
    name: 'testPage',
    component: require('./components/views/pages/testPage.vue')
  }
]

export default new VueRouter({
  routes,
  linkActiveClass: 'is-active',
  mode: 'history'
});
```

Laravel routes - web.php

```
Route::get('/{vue?}', function () {
    return view('index');
})->where('vue', '[\/\w\.-]*');

Route::get('/reservation/date/{date}', 'ReservationContoller@getScheduleForDate'); //route in question
Route::resource('/reservation', 'ReservationController');
Route::get ('/admin', 'AdminController@index');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Auth::routes();
```

How do I use my Laravel routes in conjunction with my VueJS routes?

Comment: removing the trailing / at the end of the uri ? /reservation/date/2018-11-13

Comment: Vue route should be the last ... or it will match all other routes too.

Comment: @simonecosci removing the trailing / didn't have an affect unfortunately

Comment: @simonecosci i've placed the vue routes at the end of web.php, didn't work either. Okay my bad, looks like it did have something to do with it, looks like I'm getting a 500 error, so it's something.

Comment: did you do `php artisan route:clear` ?

Comment: @simonecosci not recently, but before when I was debugging it for a couple of hours, I cleared everything including my routes. but i think you're right about the order of my routes.

Comment: finally it worked! will update my post/answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments of the OP, it happened to be the ordering of my routes in the web.php file. Here's the updated file for clarity

```
Route::get('/reservation/date/{date}', 'ReservationController@getScheduleForDate');
Route::resource('/reservation', 'ReservationController');
Route::get ('/admin', 'AdminController@index');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/{vue?}', function () {
    return view('index');
})->where('vue', '[\/\w\.-]*');
```

No changes needed to be made anywhere else, also had a typo in the original web.php file as the error response came back with a unknown controller. Just needed to fix the name.

Should have clicked when I was typing it out talking about the VueJS routes interfering with Laravel routes. I did reorganise it but the vue route slipped my mind.

If reordering the routes doesn't work, I'd go ahead and clear the cache and route

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```